# How can I sum two group by outcomes in MYSQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to obtain the following result:
Imagine I have an object table in the following format

| Name | Object id | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A. | . On |
| A | B. | . Off |
| A | C. | . Other |
| B | D. | . On |
| B | E. | . Other |
| B | F. | . Other |

And I want the following result

| Name. | count of objects with status On or Off |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |

In words, my goal is, for each name, to count the number of objects by status, which I can easily do with a group by 'Status' query, but to sum two of the possible statuses.

Thank you

Comment: Look into `conditional aggregation`.

Comment: Sorry I removed the comment, I was proposing `SELECT name, count(*) 
FROM yourtable
WHERE status IN ('.On','.Off')
GROUP BY name` .

Comment: @Arnaud I agree with that propose and don't see why to use conditional aggregation here. The queries in the answers are likely slower because they do not use a `WHERE` clause. Why don't you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Using `sum`:

```
select t.name, sum(t.status in ('. On', '. Off')) c from tbl t group by t.name
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q3yQIJ8F)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your needs, just filtering on the `status` and grouping by `name` may be enough :

`SELECT name, count(*) FROM yourtable WHERE status IN ('.On','.Off') GROUP BY name`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `conditional aggregation`.

```
select 
 name, 
 sum(case when status in ('. On', '. Off') then 1 else 0 end) as count_of_objects
from table1
group by name
```

Comment: I would either use this syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77097787/18794826, or write  `count(case when status in ('.On', '.Off') then 1 end)` instead, because otherwise, there is an ugly `ELSE` clause which is not required.